# Issues in Enabling the swagger 2 in Spring Boot java application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger

I hope you are all doing well. I am trying to enable the swagger in my spring boot and somehow I can not get it working. I took all the steps which I should have, it is really frustrating now to stick at it for a day. Here are the details.

1. Added Dependencies

```
<dependency>
           <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
           <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
           <version>2.9.2</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
           <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
           <version>2.9.2</version>
       </dependency>
```

2. Enable the swagger annotation

```
@EnableSwagger2
```

3. Create a bean with Docket Object to scan

```
@Bean
    public Docket swaggerApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("ml.XXXXXXXX"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .apiInfo(new ApiInfoBuilder().version("v1")
                        .title("Account Service API")
                        .description("Documentation Account Service API v1").build());
    }
```

My servlet context path is

```
server:
  servlet:
    context-path: /account
```

I have tried every possible URL of swagger like `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html`, `http://localhost:8080/account/swagger-ui.html`, `http://localhost:8080/account/v2/api-docs`. None of this is working. Could you please let me know if I am missing anything or doing wrong. I would really appreciate it.

Thanks ~~

Comment: What version of spring boot? If you set logging to debug you might see the config not getting picked up perhaps. M

Comment: It is 2.3.1.RELEASE, actually in logs it does shows it is mapped like this :  Mapped URL path [/v2/api-docs] onto method [springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller#getDocumentation(String, HttpServletRequest)]

Comment: Look like it is picking up the swagger but not the UI. Maybe the below blog might help
https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api

Comment: Yes in that case endpoint of /v2/api-docs should have still work, but it's not :(

Comment: I never used Swagger 2, but it probably needs a plugin configured in the POM to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by updating dependencies to this

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

And instead of `@EnableSwagger2`, replace it with `@EnableSwagger2WebMvc`

Comment: FYI @EnableSwagger2WebMvc is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring boot 3, just add the following dependency in the `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

Swagger 2.9.2 is not working properly with spring boot version 2.0 and above, So I have switched to Open API.It requires only 2 steps

1.Add dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

2. Update/Set URL properties

   ```
    springdoc:
      version: '@springdoc.version@'
      api-docs:
        enabled: true
        path: /v3/api-docs
      swagger-ui:
        path: /swagger-ui.html
   ```

Comment: is the 2nd for which file/configuration?

Comment: This is old answer, it may not work on spring boot 3.